# Do the USB 3D sound cards work on ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, usb, microphone, compatibility, external-soundcard

## Problem:

I want to purchase a external usb soundcard for my setup to power a low voltage Microphone, the bm-700.

A ton of videos have shown that it does work but I don't know if *this* particular soundcard actually works.

This is what it looks like

[image: This is what it looks like]

Does anyone know if they work on ubuntu?
Or if they don't.

And better yet, an alternative that you can confirm works on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: does it have a model name?

Comment: I can't find a model name sorry.

Comment: np. I also have a connected usb sound card without model name and it's working fine _(but it doesn't look similar at all)_.  good luck :)

Comment: I would also like to know. I am considering buying the same USB sound card as on the picture.